# How to change the Region in identity pool ID?

Tags: android, amazon-s3, region

*I am working on a mobile app. In which i am using amazon s3 service. For that i make an Identity pool. But when it created it automatically set the region in identity pool id to US-EAST-2. Now the problem is when i use this code*

```
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new 
       CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
           getApplicationContext(),
           "us-east-2:*******", // Identity Pool ID
           Regions.US_EAST_2 // Region
);
```

***On line number 5*** code **Region.US-East-2** give error that it **cannot resolved symbol US-East-2.**
Please help me here.
*Or tell me can i make an identity pool with the region i selected.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Solved:**

*Actually i was using an old version of amazon mobile sdk and US-East-2 is not included in it. When i use the latest version of amazon mobile sdk the problem solved.*

Answer (score 0):

To expand a little on Muhammad Abdullah's answer to his own question.

Using an outdated SDK is indeed the issue. I went wrong on this when looking at the developer guide (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforandroid/developerguide/setup.html) which is not kept up to date on the SDKs.

On their github page (https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-android) you can find the latest version of the SDKs without having to download them. Once you have found the current version number you can simply update the build.gradle file to reflect this newer version.

For example change `compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.+'` to `compile 'com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.4.+'` note that the third part of the version number is covered by the + so only the first two parts are relevant here.